# MVC5 lazy load logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lazy-loading

I've got a huge collection of articles. These collection gets updated by other users, creating new articles, updating them,...

To browse them, there is a "browse-view", which loads some articles. If the user scrolls to the end, it loads the next few items and so on(we all know that concept). Of course the user can choose how to items are getting sorted(creation date, update date, popularity,...).

Now lets say the user sorts the items by their popularity. He fetched the first 10 items and scrolled to the end. Now the next 10 items are getting fetched from the server. But now the database in the background got updated. The items that were popular a few minutes before are not popular anymore. So how should I update the view of the user?

Should I just load the next 10 items that were popular a few minutes ago. And how do I know them? Store them in the session?

**Edit:** The goal is to get a similar user experience like facebook, 9gag,... has.

Comment: There are many ways to handle this.  What is the requirement from the end users?  The design of this site is a great example on how to handle it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are two questions here.  1. How do you manage showing items filtered by popularity that are constantly changing; 2. If you want to show old popularity rankings, should you store them in session?  I think you should ask the first one on ux.stackexchange.com.  Based on the answer you get, you can decide how you want to technically solve this problem.  In my experience, your rankings don't have to be dynamic, they can be stored in another table, updated every 2 hours or so.  This of course isn't the best solution.